# How to retrive in Clojure from a vector of maps (Elasticseach buckets) the doc_count of a given key

Tags: clojure, bucket, edn

From a Clojure Elasticsearch aggregation query, I have a buckets vector of maps like the following where the key is a numerical identifier and the doc_count is the number of occurrences.

`:buckets [{:key 14768496, :doc_count 464} {:key 14761312, :doc_count 440} {:key 14764921, :doc_count 412}]`

Given a value like `14768496` I would like to be able to retrieve the doc_count, here `464`.

Answer (score 3):

I provided some feedback on the OP's own answer but figured it was worth providing as an answer in its own right:

```clj
user> (def buckets [{:key 14768496, :doc_count 464} {:key 14761312, :doc_count 440} {:key 14764921, :doc_count 412}])
#'user/buckets
user=> (def accounts (into {} (map (juxt :key :doc_count)) buckets))
#'user/accounts
```

This uses the transducer-producing arity of `map` as the "xform" argument to `into` so it avoids creating any intermediate lazy sequences.

You could also do `(into {} (map (juxt :key :doc_count) buckets))` which will produce a lazy sequence of vector pairs (of the key and the document count), and then "pour" it into an empty hash map.

`juxt` returns a function of one parameter that produces a vector from the application of each argument (the functions passed to `juxt`) to that parameter:

```clj
user=> ((juxt inc dec) 42)
[43 41]
```

Comment: We could really use a canonical question for "If you want to look something up by key in a list of maps, you should instead arrange to have a single map".

Comment: Makes sense. As it looks to me, it is not possible to improve the question after it was posted.

Answer (score 0):

While crafting the question I came across the following solution which I now want to share since it took me a while to find the right approach.

```
(def accounts (apply hash-map
                      (mapcat
                        #(vector (% :key) (% :doc_count))
                        buckets)))
```

This produces the following map:

```
{14768496 464, 14761312 440, 14764921 412}
```

Now the retrieval is straightforward:

```
(println (accounts 14768496))
```

Comment: #(vector (% :key) (% :doc_count)) can be replaced with (juxt :key :doc_count)

In addition, instead of (apply hash-map (mapcat ...)) you could do (into {} (map ...))

So accounts could be (into {} (map (juxt :key :doc_count) buckets))

Answer (score 0):

A different way of creating your `accounts` map:

```clj
user> (def buckets [{:key 14768496, :doc_count 464} {:key 14761312, :doc_count 440} {:key 14764921, :doc_count 412}])
#'user/buckets
user> (def accounts (zipmap (map :key buckets) (map :doc_count buckets)))
#'user/accounts
```

Alternatively ...

```clj
user> (defn find-doc-count [k buckets] (some #(when (= (:key %) k) (:doc_count %)) buckets))
#'user/find-doc-count
user> (find-doc-count 14768496 buckets)
464
```